# Writing log to gcloud Vertex AI Endpoint using gcloud client fails with google.api_core.exceptions.MethodNotImplemented: 501

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Trying to use [google logging client library](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-logging/) for writing logs into gcloud, specifically, i'm interested in writing logs that will be attached to a managed resource, in this case, a [Vertex AI](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/start/introduction-unified-platform) endpoint:

Code sample:

```
import logging
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions
import google.cloud.logging_v2 as logging_v2
from google.oauth2 import service_account


def init_module_logger(module_name: str) -> logging.Logger:

    module_logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)
    module_logger.setLevel(settings.LOG_LEVEL)
    credentials= service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(json.loads(SA_KEY_JSON))
    client = logging_v2.client.Client(
        credentials=credentials,
        client_options=ClientOptions(api_endpoint="us-east1-aiplatform.googleapis.com"),
    )
    handler = client.get_default_handler(
        resource=Resource(
            type="aiplatform.googleapis.com/Endpoint",
            labels={"endpoint_id": "ENDPOINT_NUMBER_ID", 
            "location": "us-east1"},
        )
    )
    #Assume we have the formatter
    handler.setFormatter(ENRICHED_FORMATTER)
    module_logger.addHandler(handler)
    return module_logger


logger = init_module_logger(__name__)
logger.info("This Fails with 501")
```

And i am getting:

> google.api_core.exceptions.MethodNotImplemented: 501 The GRPC target
> is not implemented on the server, host:
> us-east1-aiplatform.googleapis.com, method:
> /google.logging.v2.LoggingServiceV2/WriteLogEntries. Sent all pending
> logs.

I thought we need to enable api and was told it's enabled, and that we have: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
what could be causing the error?

Comment: I think you shouldn't override the logging endpoint with `ClientOptions`. `us-east1-aiplatform.googleapis.com` doesn't have a `WriteLogEntries` method. I think you should be using `logging.googleapis.com` [`write`](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/write). See [example](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library)

Comment: Thanks! that seemed to work

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by **@DazWilkin** in the comment, the error is because the API endpoint `us-east1-aiplatform.googleapis.com` does not have a method called `WriteLogEntries`.

The above endpoint is used to send requests to Vertex AI services and not to Cloud Logging. The API endpoint to be used is the `logging.googleapis.com` as shown in the [`entries.write`](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/entries/write) method. Refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/api-overview) for more info.

The `ClientOptions()` function should have `logging.googleapis.com` as the `api_endpoint` parameter. If the `client_options` parameter is not specified, `logging.googleapis.com` is used by default.

After changing the api_endpoint parameter, I was able to successfully write the log entries. The ClientOptions() is as follows:

```py
client = logging_v2.client.Client(
        credentials=credentials,
        client_options=ClientOptions(api_endpoint="logging.googleapis.com"),
    )
```